# Flash fullscreen projector

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, fullscreen, projector

Is there a way to do a projector fullscreen in flash but retain the proper size and tile a pattern background?  Much like an HTML page with a pattern background and main content area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can register for an event to be notified when flash enters and exits fullscreen mode when [Stage.displayState](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState) is changed, then adjust your background images scaling/tiling appropriately for each instance.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/FullScreenEvent.html

Also, you can set the [Stage.scaleMode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode) to change the scaling behaviour when going to fullscreen mode.  Play with these options and you should be able to do what you need.